# hide element completely under another element

Tags: css

I have two elements with the same dimensions one (gray) on top of the other (yellow), but I keep getting some pixels of the bottom element showing

```css
body{
  background:#31313a
}

.bottom{
    position:relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border: solid 8px #ff9800;
}

.top{
  position: absolute;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border: solid 8px #3e4148;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -8px;
  left: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class='bottom'>
  <div class='top'>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me make the bottom element (yellow) completely under the top element (gray)?

ps: I'm using Firefox for Ubuntu 99.0 (64-bit) and Here Is a screenshot of what I'm getting :
[image]

Comment: Looking at your snippet on my machine (Chrome, MacOS) I see no yellow pixels showing.  Can you share a screenshot of what you are seeing, and details about how you are reproducing this issue? (Such as browser, operating system, and any other salient details).

Comment: Although for me (Edge, macOS), I'm seeing a slight yellow shadow. Clearly varies across browsers https://share.cleanshot.com/OIoWaZ

Comment: @AlexanderNied I have The same Result as yainspan. I'm using FireFox 99.0 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just needs a bit of adjustment, use `10px` for the border and `-9px` for the positioning.

```css
body {
  background: #31313a
}

.bottom {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border: solid 8px #ff9800;
}

.top {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 10px #3e4148;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: -9px;
  bottom: -9px;
  left: -9px;
  right: -9px;
}
```

```html
<div class='bottom'>
  <div class='top'>

  </div>
</div>
```